# form submitting without performing any action rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

This is my login form

```
<%= form_for Customer.new, url: {action: :login} do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :username,placeholder: 'Username or Email' %>
    <%= f.password_field :password,placeholder: 'Password' %>
    <%= f.submit 'Login' %>
<% end %>
```

This is my controller

```
def login
    username = params[:username]
    password = params[:password]
    unless username.blank? && password.blank?
      #My code doesn't entering to this block
    end
end
```

If i submit form it is just submitted it doesn't perform any action

**Edit 1**

This is what my console return when form submitted

```
Started POST "/auth/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-08 08:23:05 +0530
Processing by AuthController#login as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"9f7TKlIspKQwX7jMSzI7XGrabgJKvnzj8Ip0OLTDtW4=", "customer"=>{"username"=>"xxx", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
  Rendered auth/login.html.erb within layouts/application (3.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 21ms (Views: 19.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check your `params` hash you'll see that those keys don't exist. Instead, you'll see that `params[:custpmer]` does and that it contains those fields. This is just how rails builds the params in a `form_for` style. So try this instead:

```
username = params[:customer][:username]
password = params[:customer][:password]
```

Comment: tried no but throwing this error `undefined method []' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: So what is in your params hash, then?

Comment: This is the one i can see in inspect `<input id="customer_username" name="customer[username]" placeholder="Username or Email" type="text">`

Comment: What does params hash means?

Comment: Well that seems to indicate my instruction was correct... Can you paste what is logged in the rails server console when you submit the form?

Comment: `params` is the name of the hash of keys/values that comes in with rails requests. If you were to add a debugger to your controller's `login` action you could then execute `params` and get the keys/values back to see what's available. In this case I'm expecting `params[:customer] to point to another hash of `username`, `password` key/values as well.

Comment: Yeah... check for typos. Your output indicates the params should be `"customer"=>{"username"=>"xxx" ...` which means `params[:customer]` should be present, but your error message seemed to indicate it wasn't. I'm assuming here that `undefined method []' for nil:NilClass` was referring to the `username = params[:customer][:username]` code?

Comment: I can find the problem. I am having login.html.erb view which has my login form and controller with action login. This is confusing when loading first time and on submitting form. Whether i have to use two action or any other way to do it in same action

Comment: You should use 2 separate actions. I'm sure it's possible not to but wouldn't be worth the confusion.